# Entity-Framework load part of object?

Tags: entity-framework

There's some code like this.

```
appScript.AppScriptDetails = Ent.AppScriptDetails.Where(c => c.AppScriptID == appScript.ID).OrderBy(c => c.SortOrder);
```

I want to load the objects, except for one string property.  What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

Project a new Entity, of the same type, but omit the property you don't want, or provide a default value for the unwanted property:

```
appScript.AppScriptDetails = Ent.AppScriptDetails
    .Where(c => c.AppScriptID == appScript.ID)
    .OrderBy(c => c.SortOrder)
    .Select(c => new AppScriptDetail
     {
        AppScriptID = c.AppScriptID,
        // Same for other wanted properties
        UnwantedStringProperty = null // Provide a default value
     });
```

Alternatively, if you just need to use the data locally, you can project an anonymous type and omit the unwanted property entirely.

Comment: Its an entity framework mapping so I can't cast "the entity or complex type cannot be constructed in a linq to entities query"

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you have 2 possibilities:

**1. Manually map needed properties**

```
appScript.AppScriptDetails = Ent.AppScriptDetails
       .Where(c => c.AppScriptID == appScript.ID)
       .OrderBy(c => c.SortOrder)
       .Select(c => new 
       {
          prop => prop,
          prop2 => prop2
       }).ToList();
```

Basically you map all properties, except the one you want ignored.

**2. Use AutoMapper** [IQueryableExtensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions)

Something like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<AppScriptDetails, AppScriptDetailsModel>()
    .ForMember(m => m.IgnoredProp,
          opt => opt.Ignore());

appScript.AppScriptDetails = Ent.AppScriptDetails
       .Where(c => c.AppScriptID == appScript.ID)
       .OrderBy(c => c.SortOrder)
       .Project().To<AppScriptDetailsModel>().ToList();
```